# Submenu show in module

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, submenu

i want to show submenu in a module means if in HOME page you have add 3 submenu and another menu has 5 submenu so i want when user click on home then show only 3 submenu of home page in module not another submenu.

it is possible ?

Comment: are the submenus separate modules? or when you say submenus, do you mean menu items? You could create 2 menus and assign each one to a separate module. Then create the menu items you wish to display on the menu on the home page, then create the menu items you wish to display on the menu on the other pages

Answer (score 1):

That is a standard behavior of the Joomla menu module.

If you want to display the submenu in a separate position, just assign the menu to two different modules. In the first module, set first and last level to 1, in the second the first to 2 and the last to all.